# merge array elements with same id but different values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have below mention form of data :-

```
Array
(
    [LegendID] => 1
    [XData] => 21/05/2016
    [YData] => 10
)
Array
(
    [LegendID] => 1
    [XData] => 22/05/2016
    [YData] => 25
)
Array
(
    [LegendID] => 1
    [XData] => 23/05/2016
    [YData] => 30
)
Array
(
    [LegendID] => 2
    [XData] => 21/05/2016
    [YData] => 43
)
Array
(
    [LegendID] => 2
    [XData] => 22/05/2016
    [YData] => 54
)
Array
(
    [LegendID] => 2
    [XData] => 23/05/2016
    [YData] => 96
)
Array
(
    [LegendID] => 3
    [XData] => 21/05/2016
    [YData] => 56
)
Array
(
    [LegendID] => 3
    [XData] => 22/05/2016
    [YData] => 78
)
Array
(
    [LegendID] => 3
    [XData] => 23/05/2016
    [YData] => 65
)
```

I have to convert it into below mention format:-

```
 Array
(
    [0] => stdclass Object
        (
            [legend_id] => 1
            [Xdata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 21-05-2016
                        )

                    [1] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 22-05-2016
                        )

                    [2] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 20-05-2016
                        )

                    [3] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 23-05-2016
                        )

                )

            [Ydata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [val] => 10
                        )

                    [1] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [val] => 20
                        )

                    [2] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [val] => 49
                        )

                    [3] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [val] => 29
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdclass Object
        (
            [legend_id] => 2
            [Xdata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 21-05-2016
                        )

                    [1] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 22-05-2016
                        )

                    [2] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 23-05-2016
                        )

                )

            [Ydata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [val] => 50
                        )

                    [1] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [val] => 70
                        )

                    [2] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [val] => 80
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => stdclass Object
        (
            [legend_id] => 3
            [Xdata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 21-05-2016
                        )

                    [1] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 22-05-2016
                        )

                    [2] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 23-05-2016
                        )

                )

            [Ydata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [val] => 40
                        )

                    [1] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [val] => 60
                        )

                    [2] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [val] => 30
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => stdclass Object
        (
            [legend_id] => 4
            [Xdata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 21-05-2016
                        )

                    [1] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 22-05-2016
                        )

                    [2] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 23-05-2016
                        )

                )

            [Ydata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [val] => 40
                        )

                    [1] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [val] => 60
                        )

                    [2] => stdclass Object
                        (
                            [val] => 30
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This is what I have so far

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) { 
    $out = array(); 
    foreach($row as $aData) { 
        $out['LegendID']=$aData['LegendID']; 
        $out['XData'][]=array('id'=>$aData['XData']); 
        $out['YData'][]=array('val'=>$aData['YData']); 
    } 
    print_r($out); 
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Actually i was trying with foreach loop but didn't get any success :(

Comment: foreach looop sounds good, but how do you expect us to help you fix it if you don't show your code? surely you didn't think we were just going to do it for you? that's not how this site works :)

Comment: I am getting the first array in $row and processing the same in the for loop

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
   {
      
    $out = array();
    foreach($row as $aData)
    {
     
     $out['LegendID']=$aData['LegendID'];
     $out['XData'][]=array('id'=>$aData['XData']);
     $out['YData'][]=array('val'=>$aData['YData']);
    }
    print_r($out);
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the array in newarray after that i had process it same, in the below mention processfor ($i=0; $iLegendID==$lastlegend )
                {

```
                $legendId =$newarray[$i]->LegendID;
                $Xdata.='{"id":"'.$newarray[$i]->XData.'"},';
                $Ydata.='{"val":"'.$newarray[$i]->YData.'"},';                  

            }
            else{
                $lastlegend=$newarray[$i]->LegendID;

                $datastring .= ' {
                                "legend_id": "'.$legendId.'",
                                "Xdata":
                                    [
                                        '.rtrim($Xdata,',').'
                                    ],
                                "Ydata":
                                    [
                                        '.rtrim($Ydata,',').'
                                    ]
                            },';

                $Xdata ='{"id":"'.$newarray[$i]->XData.'"},';
                $Ydata ='{"val":"'.$newarray[$i]->YData.'"},';

            }

        }

        $datastring .= ' {
                        "legend_id": "'.$legendId.'",
                        "Xdata":
                            [
                                '.rtrim($Xdata,',').'
                            ],
                        "Ydata":
                            [
                                '.rtrim($Ydata,',').'
                            ]
                    }';

        $Xdata ='{"id":"'.$newarray[$i]->XData.'"},';
        $Ydata ='{"val":"'.$newarray[$i]->YData.'"},';

        $datastring = '['.$datastring.']';
        $jdata = json_decode($datastring);
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code :

```
$result = array();
foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
    $result[$value['LegendID']]['LegendID'] = $value['LegendID'];
    $result[$value['LegendID']]['XData'][] = (object)array('id' =>$value['XData']);
    $result[$value['LegendID']]['YData'][] = (object)array('id' =>$value['YData']);
}
print_r((array_values($result)));
```

Here `$array` is your `$row`

Comment: yes, that is true. But the inside the array are empty, data are not get populated.
Even the code i have mentioned at the top, also does not populate data

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying??

Comment: please look into this : https://eval.in/567962

Comment: yes, i have seen
please check this too https://eval.in/568009

Comment: you are creating array in wrong way. Array key should be in single or double quote not in square bracket

Comment: check this : https://eval.in/568016

Comment: i have checked, issue is same as u suggested above. Is there any way to convert my formatted array, so that after that the process get siimple 

https://eval.in/568370

Comment: your array and my suggested array both are same.

Comment: your array is in display format and suggested array is in programmatically format

Comment: but if i am passing my array format than it won't get process and result is null. That is why i am asking to convert it to the suggested array format. I have tried a lot

Comment: hey ranjith, have any idea ? Please help

Comment: passing data in your format will cause syntax error. If you want to pass exact same in your format, you can use array keys in singe quotes like `'[xdata]'=>25`

Comment: if its possible, can i have the sample code for the  array that i have mentioned to the converted ones

Comment: actually its not possible to set array in your format. I am again saying you your format is only display behavior and it is same as suggested array

Comment: please look nto this. It may help you https://eval.in/569394

Comment: you can declare your format as string but not an array

Comment: yes, but in that case it won't get execute in for each loop as it assume it as string

Comment: yes, and its not possible to arrange your data in array format

Comment: hey, Ranjith. thanks for ur support issue is resolved

Comment: sounds good. Please share your answer here. It will be helpful for other people